# Does less Do Anything That zless Doesn't?

Tags: less

I've recently found the benefit of using `zless` to read log files that have rolled and been zipped.

Is there any functionality in `less` that isn't in `zless` that might catch me out if I alias `less` to `zless`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my Debian system, `zless` is a shellscript wrapper around `less`.

Inspection of the script shows that it sets the environment variables `LESSMETACHARS` and `LESSOPEN`, so if you are expecting those variables to have specific values when you invoke `less` you will find they have been changed when invoked via `zless`.

On a very minor note, `less --version` is different to `zless --version`, but since you're only considering an alias I don't think this is will be an issue.

Comment: +1. Also, if you have something like `export LESSOPEN="| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s"` in your ~/.bashrc, then you can just use `less`.   With that set, less will try to identify what kind of file it is (by filename "extension") and use whatever program is appropriate to list the contents - zcat for .gz etc files, bzcat for bzipped, `dpkg --info` and `dpkg --contents` for .deb, `pdftotext` for .pdf, and so on.   Run `man lesspipe` for details on recognised extensions (the man page also describes how you can extend it with ~/.lessfilter).

Comment: Very interesting